# HTML image not showing in Gmail

Tags: html, gmail, html-email, newsletter

I'm sending an e-mail newsletter in HTML. 
Inside the HTML I have something like

`<img height='70' width='70' style='display:block' src='myDomain.com/imageName.png'>`

When I open the newsletter with Thunderbird or Outlook, the image is being displayed. However, when I open it with Gmail, no image is shown.
I'm not sure if it's about the proxy that Gmail uses for security reasons or if it's something else. Either way, I'd like to know if anyone ever came across this and if so, how it was solved.

Comment: What's the actual `<img>` tag that Gmail displays (open your browser inspector in Gmail)? What URL does it use?

Comment: It uses the expected url: theProxyUrl#myURL. The problem was not the gmail proxy itself but the image was not accessible. Thunderbird and Outlook worked great because they don't use an intermediate server to access the image. Problem solved. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 74):

Late to the party but here goes... I have experienced this problem as well and it was solved with the following:

- Including the scheme in the src url (using "//" does not work - use full scheme EG: "https://")
- Including width and height attributes
- Including style="display:block" attribute
- Including both alt and title attributes

EG:

```
<img src="https://static.mydomain.com/images/logo.png" alt="Logo" title="Logo" style="display:block" width="200" height="87" />
```

Comment: width & height did it for me

Comment: I was referencing an AWS S3 URL which had "//" at the beginning of the URL. Replacing with "https://" fixed it.

Comment: i am use https://, alt, title, width,height and  style="display:block" but not showing in my html images in email...please help me.

Comment: @user3076732 did you figure this out?

Comment: It wasn't working for me with just an `alt` attribute, but adding the `title` attribute worked!

Comment: I have added alt, title, height, width, display: block still nothing worked.

Comment: Also note that if your image is an SVG it won't work either (even with all the above suggestions) and you'll need to convert it to a PNG or other supported format. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33151666/1852005

Answer (score 57):

For me, the problem was using svg images. I switched them to png and it worked.

Comment: Tried but not worked to me.

Answer (score 45):

Google only allows images which are coming from trusted source .

So I solved this issue by hosting my images in google drive and using its url as source for my images.

Example: 
with: 
http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=FILEID'>

to form URL please [refer here](http://googlesystem.blogspot.in/2013/02/permalinks-for-google-drive-images.html).

Comment: Short answer but really helpful.

Comment: Why is that @samuelkobe

Comment: @samuelkobe as of mid 2018 it seems we can still do that

Comment: @PhoenixB I believe I may have been misinformed. I am not sure what I read 2 years ago. My bad everyone. Deleted my old comment.

Comment: Thanks bro, this helped me

Comment: Are the "trusted sources" listed anywhere?  Wondering what my other options are for hosting static content besides Google Drive.  Tried Amazon S3 didn't work.

Comment: In my case I was using ngrok's autogenerated URL. Once I switched to an ngrok _domain_ (paid plan), Google trusted the images and started downloading them

Comment: This is real answer. Gmail only allow to show trusted image url.

Answer (score 11):

Please also check your encoding: Google encodes spaces as `+` instead of `%20`. This may result in an invalid image link.

Comment: My images with no spaces display fine in Gmail and Yahoo mail. My images with spaces do not display in Gmail nor Yahoo mail. So I believe either this is the issue or both clients just don't like spaces in the image names for some other reason.

Comment: Yep, on the path to our images we had a space. Using an _ instead fixed the issue for us.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue and for me it was because I was using an SVG image, once I changed to a JPG or PNG, it worked. Maybe this can assist someone who will come across the same issue. It seems Gmail doesn't support SVG images.

Comment: well you are right.... Google does not support SVG. which is kinda stupid if you ask me.

Answer (score 9):

You might have them turned off in your gmail settings, heres the link to change them https://support.google.com/mail/answer/145919?hl=en

Also gmail may be blocking the images thinking they are suspicious.

from the link above.

> **How Gmail makes images safe**
>
> Some senders try to use externally linked images in harmful ways, but
> Gmail takes action to ensure that images are loaded safely. Gmail
> serves all images through Google’s image proxy servers and transcodes
> them before delivery to protect you in the following ways:
>
> Senders can’t use image loading to get information like your IP
> address or location. Senders can’t set or read cookies in your
> browser. Gmail checks your images for known viruses or malware. In
> some cases, senders may be able to know whether an individual has
> opened a message with unique image links. As always, Gmail scans every
> message for suspicious content and if Gmail considers a sender or
> message potentially suspicious, images won’t be displayed and you’ll
> be asked whether you want to see the images.

Comment: thanks but when I first came across it that's what I thout. It's not it: "Images from this sender are always displayed"

Comment: @Rita gmail may still block images if they believe them to be suspicious, try hosting the image on a well known img site like imgur.com and then test it.

Answer (score 8):

Try to add `title` and `alt` properties to your image.... Gmail and some others blocks images without some attributes.. and it is also a logic to include your email to be read as spam.

Answer (score 7):

I noticed that Google was stripping the src attribute from my img tags. I tried every answer on this page - with no luck.

What finally worked for me was replacing img tags with divs that have background images. For example, instead of:

```html
<img style="height: 24px; width: 24px; display: block;" src="IMAGE SOURCE"/>
```

I replaced it with:

```html
<div style="height: 24px; width: 24px; display: block; background: url(IMAGE SOURCE); background-size: contain;"></div>
```

Hope this helps others who spent way too long pulling their hair out over this.

Comment: In my case, this is the solution that worked.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what was said by Howard

You have to keep in mind that Google encodes spaces as `+`
To avoid this, the ulr must be encoded in RFC 3986, which means spaces encoded at `%20`, for example:

> `https://example.com/My Folder/image 1.jpg`
>    to 
>   `https://example.com/My%20Folder/image%201.jpg`

Answer (score 2):

HTTP or HTTPS should be full address

background-image: url(http://fulladdress.com/ca/1/product_assets/T/C/X/M/K/NMTCXMK_mu.jpg)

```
var mailOptions = {
  from: 'fulladdress@gmail.com',
  to: emails,
  subject: 'i super another ma node mailer cool test',
  text: 'That was easy!',
  html: '<a href="//google.com"><div style="background-image: url(http://fulladdress.com/ca/1/product_assets/T/C/X/M/K/NMTCXMK_mu.jpg);width:500px;height:500px">ascfas</div></a>'
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I know Gmail already fix all the problem above, the alt and stuff now.

And this is unrelated to the question but probably someone experiences the same as me.

So my web designer use **"image"** tag instead of **"img"**, but the symptom was the same. It works on outlook but not Gmail.
It takes me an hour to realize. Sigh, such a waste of time.

So make sure the tag is **"img"** not **"image"** as well.

Comment: Indeed, never forget to look for the obvious (I had switched my LOGO_URL and SITE_URL).

Answer (score 2):

My issue was similar.
This is what my experience has been on testing the IMG tag on gmail
(assuming most of the organization's would have a dev qa and prod server.)

I had to send emails to customers on their personal email id's and we could see that gmail would add something of its own like following to src attribute of img tag. Now when we were sending these images from our dev environment they would never render on gmail and **we were always curious why**?

```
https://ci7.googleusercontent.com/proxy/AEF54znasdUhUYhuHuHuhHkHfT7u2w5zsOnWJ7k1MwrKe8pP69hY9W9eo8_n6-tW0KdSIaG4qaBEbcXue74nbVBysdfqweAsNNmmmJyTB-JQzcgn1j=s0-d-e2-ft#https://www.prodserver.com/Folder1/Images/OurImage.PNG
```

so an image sent to my gmail id as following never worked for me

```
<img src="https://ci7.googleuser....Blah.Blah..https://devserver.com/Folder1/Images/OurImage.PNG">
```

and our dev server we can't render this image by hitting following URL on Chrome(or any browser).

```
https://www.devserver.com/folder1/folder2/myactualimage.jpg
```

now as long as the src has www on it worked all the time and we didnt had to add any other attributes.

```
<img src="https://www.**prodserver**.com/folder1/folder2/myactualimage.jpg">
```

Comment: Hi @Sandeep. I am currently having the same issue. If you can't hit the image after adding www. How did you manage to make use of the url to be able to display the image in the email?

Comment: As long as the src attribute had www on it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I was using Cloudflare. As soon as I disabled the proxy for my host's website IP address images in Gmail appeared immediately.

I have now added a new firewall rule to allow requests where the URI contains 'googleimageproxy' and everything is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I tried another image from internet which url starts https://
it worked on gmail and outlook.
get your images from domain which has SSL.

Answer (score 0):

I am even later to this party, but after spending about 2 hours trying everything imaginable and not having any luck, I finally realized it will work if I upload the pics to GOOGLE PHOTOS instead of GOOGLE DRIVE.  Then I can right-click on the pic, copy the address, paste it in, and it works beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

In backend i created endpoint for showing images. Laravel code looks like:

```
 public function getImage($name)
 {
        return response()->file(base_path() . '/resources/img/' . $name . '.png');
 }
```

Then in my html email template i created div with background-image.

```
<div style='background: url("https://mysite1.com/api/v1/get_image/logo")'></div>
```

And it's works for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was using images name as `equity investments.png` .
 I switched them to `equity_investments.png` and it worked.

Not working :-

`<img src="https://xxxxxxx.com/webinar_images/equity investments.png" alt="" />`

Working :-

`<img src="https://xxxxxx.com/webinar_images/equity_investments.png" alt="" />`

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the suggestions this thread (setting width, height, title, full url, etc).  The final fix for me was switching from SVG to PNG did the trick for me.

I then tried removing all the other extra decorators (title, display block), and it still worked as long as I left the image type as PNG.  So, PNG seems to be the only required change.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to switch from .svg to .png and it worked!. Tried to add all properties to the svg image and gmail didn't show the image.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33941060)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was missing the `https://` in the path and had only the domain name. Added that and it started showing properly

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with AWS S3.
In section Permission i turned the option "Blocking all public access" to off and all thing works fine now

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem I also encountered. In my case, I just converted the image's SVG format to JPG, and then it worked. The reason is Gmail doesn't support SVG images.

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread once facing the same issue.
In my case, the value of `style` attribute had spaces, new lines, etc. Once I have removed them, I am able to see the styles in the email content.

Before:

```
<img 
    src="https://url"
    class="ht-files-display-image"
    style="    margin-left: auto;    margin-right: auto;      max-width: 100%;    max-height: 100%;    border-radius: 10px;"
    alt="" />
```

After:

```
<img 
    src="https://url" 
    class="ht-files-display-image" 
    style="margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;max-width: 100%;max-height: 100%;border-radius: 10px;" 
    alt="" />
```

I guess gmail simply drops the attributes that are not valid, unlike HTML, which has high tolerance for invalid markup.