# gmail not showing images from Https AWS

Tags: image, amazon-web-services, gmail, gmail-api

I recently added HTTPS to my AWS hosting. Prior to that, emails being sent out from my applications were displaying images perfectly. Now

https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/v7JpfbV4ITosgXbBdN7ze_X9624aZVxbZpVu2dDEYBZUAMyhMoLfWzwVRiOuQOsdyRD8-f4SIc24GETF8SZnD_YE=s0-d-e1-ft#https://smartalumni.ng/images/SchoolCard.png

shows:

> The requested URL: /proxy/v7JpfbV4ITosgXbBdN7ze_X9624aZVxbZpVu2dDEYBZUAMyhMoLfWzwVRiOuQOsdyRD8-f4SIc24GETF8SZnD_YE=s0-d-e1-ft was not found on this server.

That’s all we know.

While

https://smartalumni.ng/images/SchoolCard.png

displays the image perfectly.

Comment: Maybe your source is not coming from a trusted sources by google. In this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28210704), it was suggested that you have to host your image in google drive and using its url as a source of images. You can refer to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk).

Comment: Are the links in your email using http or https?  Your server appears to be redirecting http to https.  Related?

Comment: I am facing that issue too...Did you solve it?